# create new column based on max column value

Tags: sql, hiveql

i have a query which looks like this

```
select max(mytime), type, id from my table where id = 1
group by id, type
```

This gives me results similar to

```
time              type               id
2018-01-01        green              1
2017-01-03        blue               1
2017-03-03        red                1
```

I want the type to be on the same based on the max value. So it will take the max time of all similar id's in this case '1' and copy that type for all entries. It should look like

```
time              type               id
2018-01-01        green              1
2017-01-03        green              1
2017-03-03        green              1
```

Comment: why green rather than blue or red

Comment: Because green has the max value of time associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports the `first_value()` window function, so you can do:

```
select distinct max(mytime) over (partition by id, type) as mytime,
       first_value(type) over (order by max(mytime) desc) as type,
       id
from my table 
where id = 1
group by id, type;
```

This seems really strange, though.  Why would you want to get rid of the original type?

Comment: I get an error of ' SELECT DISTINCT AND GROUP BY can not be in the same query

Answer (score 0):

your can try below way using subquery

```
  select t1.time,(select type from mytable where mytime= (select max(mytime) from mytable
    where id = 1) ) as type,id
     (
     select max(mytime) as time , type, id from mytable
     where id = 1
     group by id, type
      ) t1
```